# Programming by using oops concept

Tags: oop

can you give me a idea about the following program:

There is vehicle factory. The common attribute of all the vehicles are that they can `run`. Building the basic structure of any vehicle, it is required to pass `wheel count`, `wheel size` and `factor`. The `max speed` is defined by the multiplication of `wheel count`, `size` and `factor`.

The factory can build: `Cycle`, `MotorCycle`, `Car`, `Bus`.
When those vehicle run they print `<Vehicle Name>can run at speed<Max Speed>`
Please write a program using OO approach.

```
Factor:Cycle=1,MotorCycle=2,Car=4,Bus=6
Wheel Size:Cycle=10, MotorCycle=12, Car=12, Bus=20
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I would use an object oriented programming language... seriously though, the question is not suitable for this site in its current state. Please provide more information and more importantly, ask a **specific** question.

Comment: What i have tried... i have made an abstract class which will calculate the max speed. and the other four class i.e.bus,cycle,motorcycle,car will extend the same. but get confused how should i proceed

Comment: If you cannot explain what exactly you have problems with, how can we help you? Implement the concrete subclasses according to the specification. I recommend to go through your lecture notes again. If this is homework, then all the information you need should be given in  the notes. Or have a look at online material, e.g. if you use Java, have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html.

Comment: What do you mean when you say `when those vehicle run they print`?

Comment: It means...when we run the program it will print like <vehicle name>can run at speed<speed>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read between the lines:

1. They *can* `run`: refers to a method.
2. *Building the basic structure*: refers to a constructor, in fact it sums up the constructor parameters.
3. The `max speed` is defined by the *multiplication* of ...: a calculated property.
4. The factory can build ... sums up the subtypes of `Vehicle`. (As you already understood).
5. When those vehicle run they ... : tells you what the `run` method should do.

Then the constructor parameters are given, assuming you can figure out the wheel count.

Comment: Thanks... I Have already done this...and the program is running properly..